# Not saving image from ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to save an Image from image view but i am getting exception `(Read-only file system)`

I have tried this code,

```
bitmap1 = imageView.getDrawingCache(); //for retrieving the Image

public void saveOnClick(View view)
{
    try 
    {
            String filename="qrimage";  
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage()+" Not Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added this permission to manifest file  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ?

Answer (score 1):

User permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a saving function

```
void Save() {
    final File myDir = new File(folder);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    final Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";
    file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {

        mCBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    } catch (final Exception e) {

    }
}
```

just call `Save();` in onClick of your button. 
P.S you'll have to modify the name and the Bitmap name.

--- Declare these as global

```
    static File file;
String folder = "/sdcard/Pictures/YourFolderName";
```

and don't forget to set the permission to read and write to the storage.

Comment: I am getting `Null` exception

Comment: I think it mean `bitmap` is getting null

Comment: yeah the bitmap is null, as i stated above you'll have to change the bitmap name to yours . 
Bitmap bmp = imageview.getdrawingcach(); 
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); something like this

Comment: You haven't define `out` here..what is `out`

Comment: `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);` put this inside of the try above.

Comment: sure it does !!! do u have imageview ? do u have bitmap ? do u know how to get bitmap out of imageview ? post your code. so i can help u

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public void saveOnClick(View view)
    {
        try 
        {

                imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); //UPDATE HERE
                imageView.buildDrawingCache(); //UPDATE HERE
                bitmap1 = imageView.getDrawingCache(); //UPDATE HERE

                String filename="qrimage";  
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
               e.printStackTrace();
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage()+" Not Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First make sure that your app has the storage permission enabled:

Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!

Permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So, if you want to create your own directory in your File Storage you can use somethibng like:

```
String myDate = getCurrentDateAndTime();
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = "YourFileName_"+myDate+".jpg";
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
//to refresh the gallery
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Hope this helps!